# What made Cersei change her mind in the meeting with Tyrion?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), Tyrion goes to talk with Cersei to change her mind about the truce, and afterward, he says:

> You are pregnant

She changes her mind, comes out of her palace, and proposes to send her army to fight in the North.

**So, what did Tyrion do which made Cersei change her mind so quickly?**

Or did she and Euron plan this meeting also?

Comment: 1. Tyrion never asks `Are you pregnant?`. He sees her rub her belly and interrupts her to say, `You're pregnant` 2. If you actually watch the episode, we learn that she never planned to agree to send her troops North - she even scolds Jaime for being the `stupidest Lannister` for believing so - and that her agreement with Tyrion was just a farce.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Sorry for typing the dialogue wrong. Fixed now. thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Cersei's intentions throughout this interaction?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79631/what-are-cerseis-intentions-throughout-this-interaction)

Answer (score 8):

In "Inside the Episode" after the show, one of the writers talks about this and says that Cersei is playing Tyrion here -

> It's a little bit of a poker game they're playing there, because it
>   seems like she's bluffing, and he reads her bluff, but she wanted him
>   to read her bluff. This was all part of her game. Cersei has become
>   quite good at playing this game. She wasn't in power, but she was on
>   the edges of power, and she learned how to operate in that
>   environment. And she plays Tyrion pretty beautifully here.

We know that Cersei is not really going to help them, but instead intends to take back the lands she lost, from what she said to Jaime. She simply wanted Tyrion to believe that he had convinced her to help.

Comment: Yup, and she needed Tyrion to believe that he'd not just persuaded her but cleverly outsmarted her and uncovered some new surprising leverage or vulnerability, else he'd never have believed that she meant her promise. He'll never trust her, but he does trust his own cleverness too much... and she knows it

Answer (score 3):

It appears at this point that Cersei has already agreed to the armistice though she hasn't said she won't continue taking the lands back later on:

> Cersei: Then there is nothing left to discuss. The dead will come north first. Enjoy dealing with them. **We will deal with whatever is left of you.**

When Tyrion and Cersei enter the Dragonpit later on Cersei appears to have changed her mind about the situation and now wants to send her forces to help:

> Cersei: My armies will not stand down. I will not pull them back to the capital. I will march them north to fight alongside you in the Great War. The darkness is coming for us all. We'll face it together.

However, as we know from the conversation between Cersei and Jaime later on this was a bluff:

> Cersei: What are you doing?
>   
> Jaime: Preparing the expedition north.
>   
> Cersei: Expedition north? I always knew you were the stupidest Lannister.
>   The Starks and Targaryens have united against us, and you want to fight alongside them? Are you a traitor or an idiot?
>   
> Jaime: You pledged our forces to fight our common enemy.
>   
> Cersei: I'll say whatever I need to say to ensure the survival of our house.
>   **You expect me to trust the man who murdered our father?** You expect me to command our troops to fight beside foreign scum, to fight for the Dragon Queen?
>   
> Jaime: You saw it with your own eyes. You saw a dead man trying to kill us.
>   
> Cersei: I saw it burn. If dragons can't stop them, if Dothraki and Unsullied and Northmen can't stop them, how will our armies make a difference?

So she doesn't trust them and also went back on "her word" to send the armies north. As you can see she never changed her mind she was never going to help in the first place. So why would she appear to have changed her mind? The only reason I can think of is to get rid of them.

She cancelled the meeting earlier and left them there saying she'll not fight them but she won't help them either. Then when they didn't leave, Tyrion came to talk to her, she realised it wasn't enough so she lied saying she'd help and they left.

Answer (score 0):

She later tells Jaime that it was a lie, and as soon as Danny's armies go to fight the Great War, she will take back the territories that the Lannister Army had lost to her.

So according to her words she claimed to change her mind to gain a military advantage against John and Danny.  We know this because it's the reason Jaime leaves her in the end because he says he will keep his work and ride North to help defeat the Night King.

Answer (score 0):

Cersei isn't 'changing her mind': she is simply adapting her strategy to achieve her hidden goals.

We know from her conversation with Jaime that she always intended to win the Targaryen's trust in order to betray them later down the line, when they were more vulnerable. **Any immediate support would be incredibly suspicious**, and as such she needed to present the alliance as being under certain terms, or as a heavy compromise.

Her first strategy is to appear to try and neutralize Jon Snow's intervention in the 'forthcoming war' between Danaerys and the Lannisters by holding him to account on his honor. Cersei has the appearance of gaining an advantage out of the alliance, which neutralizes suspicion.

The events in the South during this episode play quite subtly against the events in the North, where Petyr Baelish later explains the 'rulebook of manipulation' to Sansa; his 'Game' is to ask:

> What’s the worst reason they could possibly have for saying what they say, and doing what they do? Then I ask myself: how well does that reason explain what they say and do?

... so, to paraphrase; *when judging someone's actions, ask yourself what they have to gain?* ... Cersei is playing this very game, by presenting her enemies with an answer to the question.

If Jon Snow truly was, as he had previously proclaimed, not interested in the War for the Throne and focused on 'The Only War' (against the White Walkers), he would have accepted Cersei's terms. Cersei did not know, however, that Jon Snow had fallen in love with Danaerys in the interim, and as such had pledged himself to her. This was not a political move on Jon Snow's behalf, it was an act of Love: which Cersei had no way of foreseeing.

From a political perspective, she will appear in a position of weakness if she makes a demand, sees it rejected, and accepts terms anyway. Cersei has demonstrated herself as anything other than weak-willed, and capitulating at this point would be incredibly out of character; ergo **suspicious** . Snow's rejection was clearly unanticipated, but she used the opportunity to recoup her strategy.

Tyrion inadvertently provided an opportunity for Cersei's subterfuge; by realising she was pregnant. Cersei then leveraged this perceived vulnerability into an excuse to 'change her mind' about the terms she originally set out.

She would still appear weak/indecisive; but as Tyrion would inevitably report back that he learned of her pregnancy, **this decision no longer appears suspicious.**